# spark dataframe to pairedRDD in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to Spark and I want to convert dataframe to pairedRDD. My DataFrame looks like:

```
tagname,value,Minute
tag1,13.87,5
tag2,32.50,10
tag3,35.00,5
tag1,10.98,2
tag5,11.0,5
```

I want PairedRDD(tagname, value). I tried

```
val byKey:Map[String,Long] = winowFiveRDD.map({case (tagname,value) => (tagname)->value})
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: I tried with 'val byKey:Map[String,Long] = winowFiveRDD.map({case (tagname,value) => (tagname)->value})'.  But I am getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `Dataset.as`:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val df = Seq(
  ("tag1", "13.87", "5"), ("tag2", "32.50", "10"), ("tag3", "35.00", "5"), 
  ("tag1", "10.98", "2"), ("tag5", "11.0", "5")
).toDF("tagname", "value", "minute")

val pairedRDD: RDD[(String, Double)] = df
  .select($"tagname", $"value".cast("double"))
  .as[(String, Double)].rdd
```

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.spark.sql.Row` has custom `get` methods for certain datatypes.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(
("tag1",13.87,5),
("tag2",32.50,10),
("tag3",35.00,5),
("tag1",10.98,2),
("tag5",11.0,5)
)).toDF("tagname", "value", "minute")

val pairedRDD = df.map(x => (x.getString(0), x.getDouble(1) ) )

pairedRDD.collect

Array[(String, Double)] = Array((tag1,13.87), (tag2,32.5), (tag3,35.0), (tag1,10.98), (tag5,11.0))
```

You can then call `pairedRDD.collect.toMap` to convert it to a Scala Map. You have two keys called `tag1` in the question, which is incorrect.

Comment: I have tried it. In case of x.getDouble(1), I am getting error as org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 65.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 65.0 (TID 96, 10.0.0.14, executor 2): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: Can you update your question with `printSchema` of your DataFrame? If your second column `value` is String, then you should just use `x.getString(1)`

Comment: Yes value is also String. But I want them in Double, so that I can do processing further on them. Thanks

Comment: If you are totally positive that you are _always_ going to have a valid double value in that column, then you could do `x.get(1).asInstanceOf[Double]` but I'd still suggest changing the schema of your dataframe to load the column as double in the start itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the RDD.SCALA, the map returns the MapPartitionsRDD. You can not cat it to a map directly. Just remove the "Map[String,Long] " is OK.

Comment: I have already tried that. It showed error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;